# I get a "($) prefixed field '$numberDecimal' in 'price.$numberDecimal' is not valid for storage." error when trying to update a field on my back-end

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

lately I've been trying to update a price field in my mongodb database but I'm facing an annoying issue.

The collection I'm trying to modify is listingsandReviews, within the database sample_airbnb.
The field in question is made as such `price {$numberDecimal: priceVar}`.

On my back end (using Express.js DAO architecture), my update query looks as such:

```
        // console.log(roomContent.amenities)
        let price = roomContent.price.$numberDecimal

        try {
            const roomIdResponse = await rooms.updateOne(
                { _id: roomId },
                { $set: { 
                    name: roomContent.name, 
                    address: {street: roomContent.address.street}, 
                    price: {'$numberDecimal': price},
                    property_type: roomContent.property_type, 
                    bedrooms: roomContent.bedrooms, 
                    beds: roomContent.beds, 
                    minimum_nights: roomContent.minimum_nights, 
                    maximum_nights: roomContent.maximum_nights, 
                    amenities: roomContent.amenities, 
                    description: roomContent.description
                    } 
                },
            { upsert: true }
            );

            return roomIdResponse;
        } 
        catch (e) {
            console.error(`Unable to update room: ${e}`);
            return { error: e };
        }
    }
```

the shell gives me back that error `Unable to update room: MongoServerError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$numberDecimal' in 'price.$numberDecimal' is not valid for storage.`

I've been looking at every resource possible, some saying I should try `NumberDecimal()`, others `decimal128`, but nothing works so far.

You could say I could fix the issue on the front-end, but that wouldn't make the database structure consistent, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Did you find out something? I have exactly the same problem